# What are the opinions on saying Parshat HaMan?

Tags: parnassah-livelihood

I have read that there are different opninions regarding saying [Parshat HaMan](https://artscroll.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/the-chapter-of-manna.pdf). What are they; specifically the pros and cons of saying it? Are they any modern rulings on whether one should say it?

Comment: Are you seeking an opinion stating that one should not recite it?

Comment: I am seeking both sides; I see no issue saying a portion of the Torah along with a Yehi Ratzon. However, I am aware there are mixed opinions, and was curious to hear them.

Comment: Say it shnayim mikra vehched targum- segula for parnasa, brought in various seforim

Answer (score 3):

The Yerushalmi says:

> כל האומר פרשת המן מובטח לו שלא יתמעטו מזונותיו

*Whoever says Parshas HaMon is guaranteed that his parnossah won't be lacking.*

That Yerushalmi is brought down in the Tashbetz and other Rishonim

The Shulchan Orech OC 1:5 says that it is good to say Parshas Hamon (and other additional Tefilos) every day.

So why don't most people do so?

Because right before the Shulchan Orech talks about additional Tefilos he says that it is better to say less with Kavana than more without.

Saying Parsha Hamon is not some magical incantation that will give Parnossah.

The Mishna Berura 1:13 says

> ויכול לומר פרשת העקידה ופרשת המן אפילו בשבת. ואין די באמירה אלא שיתבונן מה שהוא אומר ויכיר נפלאות ד' וכן מה שאמרו בגמרא כל האומר תהלה לדוד ג' פעמים בכל יום מובטח לו שהוא בן עוה"ב ג"כ באופן זה. וטעם לאמירת כ"ז כי פרשת עקידה כדי לזכור זכות אבות בכל יום וגם כדי להכניע יצרו כמו שמסר יצחק נפשו ופרשת המן כדי שיאמין שכל מזונותיו באין בהשגחה פרטית וכדכתיב המרבה לא העדיף והממעיט לא החסיר להורות שאין ריבוי ההשתדלות מועיל מאומה ואיתא בירושלמי ברכות כל האומר פרשת המן מובטח לו שלא יתמעטו מזונותיו
>
> *You may  say the parsha of the Akeida and the Parshas HaMon even on Shabbat.  **it is not sufficient with mere saying, but rather he must think into  and and recognize the wonders of Hashem.** And so too that which they say in the gemara that anyone who says Ashrei three times every day is guaranteed that he will be a ben olam haba, is in this manner.  The reason for the saying of all this is because : the parsha of the Akedah  is in order to recall the merit of the forefathers every day, and also to humble his yetzer, just as Yitzchak was moser nefesh. **And the parsha of the Manna is such that he will believe that all his food {/livelihood} comes through special Divine direction {hashgacha pratis}, as it is written {and understood midrashically} "and the one who took more did not end up with more and the one who took less did not end up with less," to teach that increasing effort does not help at all**. It is found in Yerushalmi Berachos that anyone who says the parsha of the Manna {others have here: every day} he is guaranteed that his livelihood will not decrease.*

For most people saying Parshas Hamon every day will just end up as another thing to quickly read. They would be better off  focusing on the what is already a part of Davening than adding extra things to say.

Comment: Shulchan Orech is one of the steps in the Pesach Seder

Comment: This isn't in what we call the Yerushalmi. It still may be true, but the source is some lost Midrash not the Talmud per se.